# perl regex remove quotes from string

Tags: regex, string, perl, single-quotes

I would like to remove trailing and leading single quotes from a string, but not if a quote starts in the middle of the string.

Example: I would like to remove the quotes from `'text is single quoted'` but not from `text is 'partly single quoted'`.
Example 2: In `abc 'foo bar' another' baz`, no quote should be removed because the one on the beginning of the string is missing.

Here my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @names = ("'text is single quoted'", "text is 'partly single quoted'");
map {$_=~ s/^'|'$//g} @names;
print $names[0] . "\n" . $names[1] . "\n";
```

The or (`|`) in the regex `^'|'$` obviously also removes the second quote from the second string, which is not desired. 
I thought `^''$` would mean that it only matches if the first **and** the last character is a single quote, but this won't remove any single quote rom neither string.

Comment: What about this string: `"abc 'foo bar' another' baz"`

Comment: No quote should be removed from that.

Comment: But there are 3 single quotes in that string

Comment: I think you should add more test cases to account for edge cases.

Comment: What about: ($result = $text) =~ s/[']//mg;

Comment: How this text should be treated: "'text is single quoted with a ' quote in the middle'" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

```
s/^'(.*)'$/$1/
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line. `.*` greedily matches any character zero or more times.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @names = ("'text is single quoted'", "text is 'partly single quoted'");
s/^'(.*)'$/$1/ for @names;

print $names[0], "\n", $names[1], "\n";
```

Output:

```
text is single quoted
text is 'partly single quoted'
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this regexp?

```
/^'([^']*)'$/$1/
```

The rationale is: "substitute a any string starting and ending with a single quote, and that does not contain a single quote, with the string itself (starting and ending quotes excluded)"...

You can test it here: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uL2rT8/1)

Full code should be:

```
my @names = ("'text is single quoted'", "text is 'partly single quoted'");
s/^'([^']*)'$/$1/ for @names;

print join "\n", @names;
```

Which outputs:

```
$ perl test.pl
text is single quoted
text is 'partly single quoted'
```

Comment: It's exaclty what was asked for by OP... :-)

Comment: Where have you seen that?

Comment: @JE SUIS CHARLIE: yes, you could be right, OP does not specify behaviour for quoted text with a quoute in the middle, too... :-(

Comment: The whole question is very badly posed. This is just as valid as the accepted answer with the given information.